# Why Consumable Product is purchased for multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, product

I have created consumable product for In App purchase in Appstore connect.Whenever I buy the items I am able to purchase Why it is not showing that the product is already purchased????

Comment: You can buy consumable product again and again. You should check what different types of products mean: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: yeah...But for me each time transaction is being made.If it is consumable, when i purchase for a second time it will be for free right??? @user28434

Comment: No, you won't get it for free. Each time you purchase a **consumable** you will get another one for the price. And user consumes them while using your app. They can come and go multiple times. Check the link from the previous comment, and try to understand what **consumable** means.